# Getting the Modify Method Name of Java Class when comparing to Head in GIT

Tags: java, git, jgit

Is there way to get the modified method name in java class ? I can easily get the modified class name when comparing to head by using commands like :
git ls-files --modified
git diff --name-only
git diff --name-status
git diff master --compact-summary

these commands give me the .java files in which i make the changes , but i want to get the method names.

Is there any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Plain git doesn't have such functionality. Also what you've wrote above is not entirely true as the command wouldn't show you names of non public classes which were modified (a few classes defined in one `java` file).

What you need to do to achieve that is to parse the commit's diff searching for valid method declarations.